# Proof: distance less than all small epsilon implies distance zero

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Having trouble putting together a proof for this. Can I get a verification if I am correct or not?

Problem:
Prove if $|x-y|< \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$ then $x=y$.

Attempt:
Assume $|x-y|<\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$ then

let $\epsilon =\frac{|x-y|}{2}$

then $0<\epsilon<|x-y|$ a contradiction so $|x-y|=0$ and $x=y$

Answer (score 3):

It might be a bit cleaner to start the contradiction like this: Suppose $x \ne y$.  Then, $|x-y| = \delta > 0$ for some fixed $\delta$.  Let $\epsilon = \delta/2$.  Then, $|x-y|>\epsilon$, a contradiction.